# Changing shortcut for inserting a quotation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

Whenever you write a question or an answer you get this cool editor that gives you the means of inserting common markdown (quotation, code, hyperlinking etc.).

Now imagine the following situation - you accidentally click outside of that editor (a common issue if you use the damn notebook trackpads). If you are on **Linux** there is a **high chance** that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> closes the web browser's window. Bummer! I don't know how it is on MacOS (I think it was <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) but this can screw things up with the process of posting stuff.

I would like to propose to either change the quotation shortcut OR (even better) perhaps allow the assignment of custom hotkeys so that no matter which OS the user is using accident like the one I've described above have even lesser chance of happening.

Comment: According to [this comparison table](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm) (which may be somewhat outdated) ctrl+q will exit the browser in firefox (on linux only),  and safari. On internet explorer it will toggle quick view. Other than that, no other browsers reserve the ctrl+q combination.

Comment: `Ctrl+Q` is in general used for quitting an application in Linux. Of course it depends on the distro, window manager AND the application itself. For example I use XFCE on Debian and many of the applications can be close by triggering that key-combo.

Comment: I use Fedora 23 with Gnome 3.18 and the only thing that key combo is used for is Mozilla, which I never use. That isn't to say that it isn't a problem, just to say that implying it is widely used across Linux is overstating the issue. Currently KDE does not use ctrl + q for anything, though individual applications may.